# Move all files from one folder to another, based on a list

Tags: scripting, mv

I have a list of files, which I would like to move from folder `A` to folder `B`, but I do not want to do that by hand. Is there an easier way to loop through the list and move every file which is on that list?

Comment: It's close, but the duplicate target is a more complex situation as the list of files to move contains leading whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you have only file names. This is the simplest way to do that I think:

```
while IFS= read -r file; do mv -v "dirA/$file" "dirB/$file"; done < listfile.txt
```

Answer (score 9):

You could use `rsync` to move them, assuming your list of files is one filename per line.

```
rsync -av --remove-source-files --files-from filelist.txt sourceDir/ targetDir/
```

If your files are absolute names (i.e. the names begin with `/`) the `sourceDir` should be `/`. Otherwise it should be the root of the relative names.

Example

```
$ mkdir src dst
touch src/{one,two,three}
$ cat >filelist.txt <<EOF
one
two
EOF

$ ls src
one  three  two
$ ls dst

$ rsync -av --files-from filelist.txt --remove-source-files src/ dst/
building file list ... done
one
two

sent 165 bytes  received 70 bytes  470.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00

$ ls src
three
$ ls dst
one  two
```

Answer (score 5):

If you gave GNU core utilities (or other implementations with these specific features) you can use `xargs` to build an argument list for `mv` based on the file list:

```sh
cd A
xargs -rd '\n' -- mv -t B -- < file-list.txt
```

Without GNU utilities you can still use a while-read loop. In Bash that could be:

```
while IFS= read -r file; do
    mv "A/$file" "B/$file"
done < file-list.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

You can easily solve this in **ViM** with these 10 simple steps:

1. Open the long list of filenames in ViM.
2. Type `qa` to start recording a macro named "a".
3. Type `y$` to yank (copy) the filename.
4. Type `imv A/` to write "mv A/" in front of the filename, then press `Escape`.
5. Type `A B/` to write " B/" at the end of the line, then press `Escape`.
6. Type `pj^` to paste the filename and move to the beginning of the next line.
7. Press `q` to stop recording the macro.
8. Type `VG:normal @a` to replay the "a" macro until the end of the file.
9. Type `:wq rename.sh` to save as a bash script named "rename.sh" and quit.
10. Then finally, at the bash prompt, type `chmod +x rename.sh; ./rename.sh` to mark the script as executable and run it.

Comment: `:%s!\(.*\)!mv "A/\1" "B/"!` is equivalent to your steps 2-8. But not as easy to read, I'll grant.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a POSIX compliant variant without using loops. Items in `file-list.txt` are separated by newlines.

```
cd A ; xargs -I{} -- mv -- {} B < file-list.txt
```

Obviously this variant does not allow file names containing newlines. Additionally it invokes the `mv` command for every file individually.

The [variant by David Foerster](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/377444/19702) uses GNU extensions of `xargs` and `mv`. It will invoke single instance of  `mv` for multiple arguments and will be more efficient for long lists of files. It still does not allow file names containing newlines. To overcome this limitation you can use the `-0` option and separate the file names by `\0` (NULL) characters.

```
cd A ; xargs -r0 -- mv -t B -- < file-list.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

`cpio` is a standard Linux archiver that also includes a pass-though mode that makes a convenient way to copy things.

It takes a list of file on standard input, usually this is usually scripted as the output of the `find` command, but since you already have a list of files, lets use that.

assuming the filenames in the list are relative

`cd A; cpio --format=newc -pduv B < filelist.txt`

instructing `cpio`, given a list of file names on stdin, to pass-through, make directories, unconditionally write over anything already there and print a verification line, targeting directory B.  Using the `newc` format allows more than 65536 inodes, just in case you are dealing with that many

Comment: You probably want `-m` in there too, to preserve files' permissions and modification time. It doesn't move the files, though. You could add `-l` to hard-link them, and then use the same list of files to remove the source files, but that's more than your one-liner.